# classloader.getSystemResourceAsStream returns null

Tags: java, properties, classloader

I'm trying to load a properties file without using the actual path of the file. I've already done that on some other simple apps using:

```
InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);
props.load(inputStream);
```

But this time it doesn't work. The inputStream is null for some reason. PROPERTIES_FILE is a constant defined as "app.properties". I tried to remove the .properties extension and got the same results.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is app.properties located?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The PROPERTIES_FILE constant should include the package as well as the properties file (e.g. "com/some/library/file.properties".

```
    final static String PROPS_FILE = "/com/some/library/file.props";
                     //The preceding  "/" is dependendant on wheterh 
                     //you are going to be giving a relative or absolute location
    InputStream is = YourCurrentClass.class.getResourceAsStream(PROPS_FILE);
```

Comment: I've added the package information as you mentioned but still got the same error. BTW the method where I'm doing that call is static if that helps any...

Comment: Actually there was a typo when I added the package name. That solution worked great. Thanks! :)

Comment: You probably want to call getResourceAsStream on your class' class loader. Or probably on your class' Class.

Comment: I believe the actual problem was he was using "ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream" which looks for system resources.  There is a slight difference.  This is a good discussion:  http://www.coderanch.com/t/369908//java/ClassLoader-getSystemResourceAsStream

Comment: I have the very same problem. I have a spring web application and I want to load an xml file for testing purposes. It is located at
    WebContent/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/testing/document.xml
I've tried
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/testing/document.xml");
but it ends with a null. I tried to omit the initial "/" but it's the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.

Reason: I renamed `DAO` package to `dao`. While exploding the `artifact`, directory `DAO` not get overwritten.

So I got `dao` in project internals and `DAO` in filesystem :facepalm:

Answer (score -1):

When [`getSystemResourceAsStream`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) returns `null`, it means the resource was not found. Make sure the requested resource really is on the classpath at the specified location.

Comment: It answers the question really precisly, but does not support helping to solve the problem.